# Laravel collection get min by key

Tags: laravel, collections

I'm trying to find a way to get the minimum amount of a collection and return it with the id as well. Pretty sure there is a quick way around it but could not find a solution yet.

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->push(['id' => 3, 'count' => 24]);
$collection->push(['id' => 43, 'count' => 14]);
$collection->push(['id' => 11, 'count' => 84]);

dd($collection->min('count'));
```

When I do that, it only returns the "count" value. I need to retrieve the minimum count with the id it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min()` method only returns the value for the given key, not the whole row. Thankfully, the `sortBy()` method is available, and combined with `->first()`, should get you what you need:

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->push(['id' => 3, 'count' => 24]);
$collection->push(['id' => 43, 'count' => 14]);
$collection->push(['id' => 11, 'count' => 84]);

$minRecord = $collection->sortBy('count')->first();
dd($minRecord); // ["id" => 43, "count" => 14]
```

References:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first